# android phone cant find telephony.smsmanager

Tags: android

Hi
I am testing an app (android 2.1 level7) on a HTC Hero phone (via Perfecto Mobile).  I get the Foce Close msg and look at the log which says:-

```
11-30 18:41:25.765: ERROR/dalvikvm(2158): Could not find method android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault, referenced from method com.AccidentAlert.ListViewLoader.sendSMS
```

The code which calls this is:_

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneno,null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Can anyone suggest why the phone should have a problem like this?
Thanks
Ron

Comment: I am wondering why the layout has been edited - I thought the original was clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your HTC Hero hasn't been updated to Android 2.1? I believe they were 1.5 originally, which would cause this problem since the SmsManager wasn't introduced until API Lvl4 (Android 1.6).